# How to construct the normalized set of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have read the paper [Narrow Reliability Bounds for Structural Systems](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03601217908905329).

The author stated on page 458 that there exists a transformation such that a $n$-set of random variables $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ can be normalized. Here, the term ***'normalized'*** means transforming $X$ into a set of variables $Y=(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ with all means equal to zero, all standard deviations equal to one, and all covariances equal to zero.

The author further stated that

> It is well known from the general theory of random variables that such a transformation exists if the covariance matrix of $X$ is regular.

$X$ in the above quotation is the original $n$-set of random variables before normalization.

I was wondering how to construct such a transformation to *make all covariances equal to $0$*. Besides, I was also wondering what the term '*regular*' means in the above quotation.

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true whenever $Cov(X,X)$ is invertible.

Assuming $E[X_i^2]<\infty$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, we know $Cov(X,X)$ is a symmetric and positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrix.  It has the decomposition into a product of three $n\times n$ matrices:
$$ Cov(X,X) = U\Lambda U^{\top}$$
where $UU^{\top}=U^{\top}U=I$ (with $I$ being the $n \times n$ identity matrix) and $\Lambda$ is purely diagonal with nonnegative diagonal elements $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$. If $Cov(X,X)$ is invertible then $\lambda_i>0$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Assuming $Cov(X,X)$ is invertible we can define the following invertible $n \times n$ matrix:
$$ A = VU^{\top}$$
where $V$ is a purely diagonal $n\times n$ matrix with entries $1/\sqrt{\lambda_1}, ..., 1/\sqrt{\lambda_n}$ on the diagonal. This makes sense since $\lambda_i>0$ for all $i$. Define $$Y=A(X-E[X])$$
Then $E[Y]=0$ and
$$Cov(Y,Y) =Cov(AX,AX) = ACov(X,X)A^{\top} = V \Lambda V = I$$

---

The sequence $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_n$ is called the "innovation sequence" and can also be obtained by the Gram-Schmidt procedure of linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you also provide some useful links to learn about the so-called 'innovation sequence'? I have googled it but got confused.

Comment: It is in Chapter 3 of the Hajek "Random Processes" book (related to Kalman filter) and I googled to find a set of notes here: http://sims.princeton.edu/yftp/ApplEmet14/Innovations.pdf

Comment: That helps me a lot. Thanks again.